# Mask out pixels by array length in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, array

I have an image array resulting from the continuous change detection algorithm. Because arrays represent the characteristics of each break in the image series, the pixels have different array lengths.

I have code from the supporting tutorial for extracting the date of the first object in the array, after masking out zeroes:

```
var palettes = require('users/gena/packages:palettes');

var ccdResults = ee.Image("users/salem043/Locusts/ccdTiles/ccd_tile_4");

//Find change dates and change probability
var change = ccdResults.select('tBreak');
print(change, "All temporal breaks");
var changeProb = ccdResults.select('changeProb');


// Set the time range (2014 disturbances) and get as mask of 
// places that meet the condition.
var start = 2013;  
var end = 2014; 

//Create a mask of only dates within range and changeProb equal to 1
var mask = change.gt(start).and(change.lte(end)).and(changeProb.eq(
1));

// Map.addLayer(changeProb);
// print(changeProb);


//  -----------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Find the date of the first break detected in 2014
//  -----------------------------------------------------------------------

//Array Pad removes all of the entries that are 0 throughout
var dates = change.arrayMask(mask).arrayPad([1]);

//Use dates object to get layer of first date of disturbance
var firstChange = dates
    .arraySlice(0, 0, 1)
    .arrayFlatten([
        ['firstChange']
    ])
    .selfMask();
 
};
```

But I cannot obtain the image of the second change (using arraySlice) until I remove all of the gridcells in the dates image array that have a length of 1 (didn't have a second break). How do I do this?

[Full code here.](https://code.earthengine.google.com/030763829cf7e2040f7cbefe596b65d8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
var withTwo = ccdResults.updateMask(
  ccdResults.select('tBreak').arrayLength(0).gt(1)
)
```

Note that I didn't use your date constraints, as you don't typically get more than one segment per year.